# The procedure entry point interlockedcompareexchange@12 could not be located in the dynamic link library SDL2_ttf.dll

Tags: visual-studio, sdl, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

I was studying SDL2 with LazyFoo's tutorial, everything was ok before I came to import the SDL2_ttf library, I import this library into my vs2015 the same way as I import SDL2_image library, but it seems not to work...

When I tried to run the problem I wrote that contains the SDL2_ttf, I got an error window that shows the mistake **The procedure entry point interlockedcompareexchange@12 could not be located in the dynamic link library libfreetype-6.dll**, how can I fix it ?

Comment: Have you included all of the DLLs that come with the library in your output folder (same location as your .exe) or wherever you have set the DLL location to within VS?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fixed it, I just put all the `.dll` file into the vs working directory, then it works. I don't why other `.dll` can work as long as I set the path into where they are, but `SDL2_ttf.dll` can not...